# Why suddenly the never-loading pixel and headers?

Tags: bug, status-norepro

For the past week I've been getting two items on every page load which fail to load. The browser just spins and spins, never completing any page load. These items don't *appear* to directly impact site display or use, but it is interesting to see *any* page never actually finish loading.

The two items are listed by Chrome Dev Tools as:

- http://pixel.quantserve.com/pixel;r=389843796;a=p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc;fpan=0;fpa=P0-647851496-1405641054385;ns=0;ce=1;cm=;je=1;sr=2560x1600x24;enc=n;dst=1;et=1413987370991;tzo=420;ref=http%3A%2F%2Fmeta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com%2F;url=http%3A%2F%2Fgraphicdesign.stackexchange.com%2F;ogl=type.website%2Cimage.http%3A%2F%2Fcdn%252Esstatic%252Enet%2Fgraphicdesign%2Fimg%2Fapple-touch-icon%402%252Epng%3Fv%3D5078cbcb62f3%2Ctitle.Graphic%20Design%20Stack%20Exchange%2Cdescription.Q%26A%20for%20Graphic%20Design%20professionals%252C%20students%252C%20and%20enthusiasts%2Curl.http%3A%2F%2Fgraphicdesign%252Estackexchange%252Ecom%2F

and

- wss://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/

This seems to affect both the main site and meta as well as any other SE site I visit.

I don't see what use a screenshot is since I provided the direct urls but here's a screenshot....

[image]

Note the two "Pending" items -- They never actually load.

Comment: Nope. I haven't changed a thing here.

Comment: @MrE.Upvoter I added a screenshot.. but that's largely irrelevant since I provided the exact URLs which are failing to load.

Comment: @Scott the provided direct link loads for me without issue. Are you still experiencing this issue?

Comment: @Haney No, problem today. The issue seems to have resolved over this past weekend.

Comment: @Scott how strange. It's possible that the Quantserve service was having issues. I cannot reproduce it currently.

Comment: @Scott I'm having this issue too now, on the Home page. Do you as well?

Comment: @Yisela Things have been fine for me for a week or so now. Pages are loading fine for me at the moment. It's possible you're getting a different route though (clearly you would based on geolocation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up. While I have no doubt that the issue existed a few days ago, it appears to have resolved itself at present. I am unable to reproduce the non-loading behavior described. It seems that maybe the Quantserve service was having issues over the weekend, but has since resolved them. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Yes. Things seem to have sorted themselves over this past weekend. All pages are loading as expected currently. Thanks!

Comment: @Haney I'm getting this issue again, (only) on the home page for GD. The loading icon never goes away.

Comment: @Yisela no repro here, what pixel or URL is causing it?

Comment: Now the home is ok but the loading is happening [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/41669/psd-2-html-conversion). I can't reproduce on other machines though. Request URL: wss://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Yisela that probably means the browser isn't reliably supporting web sockets... What browser are you using? What OS?

Comment: Chrome 38.0.2125 on Windows 8. Firefox seems alright. This is the first time I see this issue, and it keeps "moving" around pages, so... a tricky one.

Comment: @Yisela irritating indeed. I'd say crack open a new meta post for this, and we can investigate as details / other claims arise.